# All my web service methods exposed no matter @WebMethod

Tags: java, web-services, ejb

I created a session bean(3.x) and put it in a EAR. The sessionbean code is below:

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
@WebService()
public class MESinvokeBean implements MESinvoke {

     @WebMethod()
     public void MESInvoke1()
     {System.out.println("1");}

     public void MESInvoke2()
     {System.out.println("2");}

     public void MESInvoke3()
     {System.out.println("3");}

}
```

The MESinvoke class is below:

```
@Remote
public interface MESinvoke {

}
```

After I deployed it to a wildfly server. I test is using SOAP Ui and all the three methods are exposed despite I only add @WebMethod annotation to one method. Could someone tell me what's wrong? Thx?

Answer (score 0):

This is the behaviour defined by the JAX-WS specification. From "The Java API for XML-Based Web Services (JAX-WS) 2.3", §3.3:

> A Java class (not an interface) annotated with a javax.jws.WebService annotation can be used to define a Web service.
>
> In order to allow for a separation between Web service interface and implementation, if the WebService annotation on the class under consideration has a endpointInterface element, then the interface referred by this element is for all purposes the SEI associated with the class.
>
> Otherwise, the class implicitly defines a service endpoint interface (SEI) which comprises **all of the public non-static or non-final methods that satisfy one of the following conditions**:
>
> 1. They are annotated with the javax.jws.WebMethod annotation with the exclude element set to false or missing (since false is the default for this annotation element).
> 2. **They are not annotated with the javax.jws.WebMethod annotation but their declaring class has a javax.jws.WebService annotation**.